# Removed duplicates in bash history appearing again after relogin

Tags: bash, command-history

I recently added `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` in my `bashrc` to avoid having duplicates in the history, this is working when I check using the `history` command, but the changes are not getting saved between sessions.

I can run the following sequence:

```
history | grep -w ls  # shows ls command repeated many times
ls
history | grep -w ls  # now all the duplicates are gone as expected
exit
```

After relogin, `history | grep -w ls` again shows all the duplicates of `ls`. Why do these duplicates reappear in this case?

Update : I could use `history -w` at the end of a session and the commands from the session are not duplicated after relogin.